# <ins> element shoving content in separate div further down page

Tags: html, css

Why is the text in my `<p>` element being pushed down because of the existence of the `<ins>` tag? If you delete the `<ins>` tag from DOM via developer tools, you will see my text gets put in the position I expect.

```css
main {
    max-width: 1000px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

#portal-wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 40px 0;
    background: #fff;
}

aside {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px 20px 20px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    position: relative;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 795px) {

    main {
        display: table;
    }

    #portal-wrapper {
        display: table-cell;
        min-width: 400px;
        max-width: 680px;
        width: auto;
    }

    aside {
        width: 300px;
        display: table-cell;
        padding-right: 0;
        padding-top: 41px;
    }

}
```

```html
<main>
    <div id="portal-wrapper">
        <div id="portal">
            <p>
              Here's my text. Why am I pushed down so far.
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <aside>
        <ins style="display: block; height: 600px;">      </ins>
    </aside>
</main>
```

Fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/wwvq7net/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [vertical-align: top](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align) property:

```css
main {
    max-width: 1000px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

#portal-wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 40px 0;
    background: #fff;
}

aside {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px 20px 20px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    position: relative;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 795px) {

    main {
        display: table;
    }

    #portal-wrapper {
        display: table-cell;
        vertical-align: top;
        min-width: 400px;
        max-width: 680px;
        width: auto;
    }

    aside {
        width: 300px;
        display: table-cell;
        vertical-align: top;
        padding-right: 0;
        padding-top: 41px;
    }

}
```

```html
<main>
    <div id="portal-wrapper">
        <div id="portal">
            <p>
              Here's my text. Why am I pushed down so far.
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <aside>
        <ins style="display: block; height: 600px;">      </ins>
    </aside>
</main>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sergdenisov/rfknfwq7/)

Answer (score 1):

When you set `display:table-cell` those elements are automatically starting with `vertical-align:baseline` which is why your `#portal` is being pushed to the bottom of `#portal-wrapper`.

Change to `vertical-align:top` or another value to fix this. Read more about [vertical-align here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align).